# Accessing private members inside a MATCHER

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I am verifying the private members of `Object` (`Values` storing the internal state of the class) via a `MATCHER` in a unit test however I have the following concern:

- I created `GetValueA()` and `GetValueB()` public interfaces solely so that unit test could access inside a `MATCHER`. Doesn't sound like a right idea (specially if it's not supposed to be publicly exposed) but is there a way to access `valueA` and `valueB` inside a `MATCHER` somehow without having to create *public* methods? (could be set to private/protected perhaps so it's not publicly exposed)

`MATCHER_P2` could be brought inside the `Object` class but how would the caller invoke it?

[Live sample](https://godbolt.org/z/v1MGxP51M)

```
template<typename T>
class Object
{
    // internal to the class
    struct Values
    {
        int valueA = 100;
        int valueB = 0;
    };

    Values values = {};
    T otherStuff;

    public:
    // only exposing for the sake of Unit test access
    int GetValueA() const
    {
        return values.valueA;
    }

    int GetValueB() const
    {
        return values.valueA;
    }
};

MATCHER_P2(Match, m1, m2, "")
{
    return ExplainMatchResult(m1, arg.GetValueA(), result_listener) &&
           ExplainMatchResult(m2, arg.GetValueB(), result_listener);
}

class UnitTest 
{
  TEST(UnitTest, testA)
  {
     Object<int> object;
     EXPECT_THAT(object, Match(Ne(0), Eq(0))); 
  }
};
```

Comment: Unit test are typically for testing the public interface of the class, but if you really want to test the private members, I think you can use `friend ` to test private members

Comment: `Object` could use `friend class UnitTest` but how does `MATCHER` get to access the private members?

Comment: You should declare in your class that testclass is going to be a friend class, and inside the test you can access the private members

Comment: I mean the private members are to be accessed inside `MATCHER` and `MATCHER` isn't a part of the `UnitTest`. How do you think private members are accessed inside `MATCHER?`

Comment: Why do you need a matcher?

Comment: I don't wanna be invoking `EXPECT_NE/EXPECT_EQ` for each member in the caller and rather leave it to a separate function (i.e, MATCHER) to take care of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the private member to the matcher, and define the test to be a friend class.

Also use `FRIEND_TEST` macro instead of `friend class`.

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Object
{
    // internal to the class
    struct Values
    {
        int valueA = 42;
        int valueB = 0;
    };
    FRIEND_TEST(UnitTest, testA);
    Values values = {};
    T otherStuff;

};

MATCHER_P2(Match, m1, m2, "")
{
    return ExplainMatchResult(m1, arg.valueA, result_listener) &&
        ExplainMatchResult(m2, arg.valueB, result_listener);
}

TEST(UnitTest, testA)
{
    Object<int> object;
    EXPECT_THAT(object.values, Match(Ne(0), Eq(0)));
}
```

Live example: https://godbolt.org/z/WWr3vrWsn

Comment: Thanks. Would it make more sense to access a private member variable `valueA` or a private getter `GetValueA()` inside MATCHER? I guess it's more of a preference thing?

Comment: I think a matcher should be considered as a function that accepts a certain variable type. It's up to the caller to provide variables that the function has access to. When you define a function, do you care about the parameters of the function to be public or private, or do you make sure the caller of that function provides values that are accessible?

Comment: I am referring to something like `ExplainMatchResult(m1, arg.GetValueA(), result_listener)` where `GetValueA()` is a private getter in `Object`

Answer (score 0):

As mention in the comments, in principle is not the best idea to unit test private members, but sometimes that is what you want/need.

If this is the case, you might want to go making the testclass a friend class:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Object
{
    friend class UnitTest_testA_Test; // pay attention to the name
                                      // it should be Test at the end (Uppercase 'T')
    struct Values
    {
        int valueA = 42;
        int valueB = 0;
    };
};

TEST(UnitTest, testA)
{
    Object<int>  object;
    EXPECT_EQ(42, object.values.valueA);
}
```

And since you want to use a matcher:

```cpp
MATCHER_P2(Match, m1, m2, "")
{
    return ExplainMatchResult(m1, arg.values.valueA, result_listener) &&
           ExplainMatchResult(m2, arg.values.valueB, result_listener);
}
```

Comment: But I mentioned I don't wanna be invoking `EXPECT_EQ` in the caller for each member function. It defeats the purpose of having a MATCHER